# Similarities between OBD-II and VGA

Tags: electrical-engineering, computer-engineering, computer-hardware, car

I'm working on a project to make a Heads Up Display in my car.  I need a way to present my project in front of my class, for I obviously cannot bring my car into the presenting room.  My professor told me to look into an OBD-II simulator, and since then everything I looked into has a VGA connection(like this one: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9555).  I've tried looking into this, but I was not able to find anything.  Everything that I read talks a lot about VGA, but never explains why OBD-II used VGA.  It seems to me that an OBD-II connection is completely different from a VGA connection, and a VGA is for old computer monitors. So my question is: what are the similarities between an OBD-II connection and a VGA connecting, and why do these simulators use a VGA connection?

Comment: Your professor most likely meant to use an OBD-II simulator to generate the data that you would display through your HUD.  You'll then need to feed the data from the generator into another device that would build the display for the HUD.  But the only person who can really answer that question is your professor.

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted is not an ODB-II simulator, it is an ODB-II interface you can plug into your car. If you have read the [Hook-up Guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/obd-ii-uart-hookup-guide?_ga=2.47668391.1816384797.1522928605-744497538.1522928605) on the website, you'll have noticed that the interface port is a DB9 connector, usually used with serial connections, this one uses the UART protocol it seems. Furthermore, I haven't read anything about VGA in your link.

The ODB-II *emulator* you're looking for will be something like the [Freematics emulator](https://freematics.com/pages/products/freematics-obd-emulator-mk2/) (I literally typed into Goole: *odb-ii simulator* and it was the first link Google gave me.) It can be controlled via your PC to simulate the signals as if it were a real car and sends the signals over an ODB-II connector, exactly as you would find in your car, which you could use for your demo. And the whole thing fits in your trouser pocket.

Edit:

What you may perhaps have come across might be some ODB-II interfaces with it's own proprietary firmware and OS with a VGA output you can directly connect to a screen without requiring additional software. I haven't seen something like this, but I can think that it should exist.